# Get instance of currently running activity?

Tags: android, events, android-activity

What i am trying to do is to dispatch the motion event to currently running activity . I have got the ComponentName of the current activity from this code

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

// get the info from the currently running task
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

Log.d("current task :", "CURRENT Activity ::" + 
            taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
```

Now that I have the component name, I want to dispatch the event

```
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
```

that is in the `Activity` class, and to do this I need an instance of the current activity. I am stuck at component name. How can I get the `Activity` instance so that I can dispatch the event?

Comment: please put a little more effort into formatting your code next time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow, there are so many things wrong with this question it is hard to know where to start!  Let's take them in order:

> What i am trying to do is to dispatch the motion event to currently running activity

The current foreground activity will get motion events, unless it should not.  The only way I can imagine this making any sense is that your service has put a system window up that is going on top of all the apps...  and in that case, I would urge you to not do this and just let your foreground activity handle the event.

> I have got the ComponentName of the current activity from this code

ActivityManager.getRunningTasks() is *not* for normal application development.  This is intended for things like task managers and such.  You should never write core program logic that has dependencies on the information returned by this function.  That is begging for trouble, and in fact I can guarantee such code will break at some point.  (What happens when multiple applications can be running in the front at the same time?)

> I want to dispatch the event

You really, really should not be ripping motion events out of one window and stuffing them in to another.  Various dispatch state will not be set up correctly, state in the event will not be consistent (the event was set up with an origin and such for the original window, not the new one you are stuffing it in), etc.  This is another great way to make a flaky application that has a good chance of breaking in the future, if you can even kludge it to make it work at all today.

> I am stuck at component name. How can I get the Activity instance so that I can dispatch the event?

Indeed, all you have is a component name.  That has nothing to do with active instances.  There is no magic way to turn this into an actual instance.  It would be wrong to supply one, because this can easily be ambiguous (if there were two instances of that class instantiated).

I think you need to back-up to the start and look at what you are actually trying to accomplish, to get help on what a reasonable way of approaching it is.  The path you have gotten yourself down is at this point pretty terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer , but why these methods are there in the API , there will be someway to use them

Comment: Methods like boolean  dispatchGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent ev)
Called to process generic motion events.
boolean  dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
Called to process key events.
boolean  dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(KeyEvent event)
Called to process a key shortcut event.
boolean  dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)
Called to process population of AccessibilityEvents.
boolean  dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
Called to process touch screen events.
boolean  dispatchTrackballEvent(MotionEvent ev)
Called to process trackball events.

Comment: Basically I am not interested in that this method will crash the application someday , i have to make it in running condition despite of these special cases that you have mention .

Comment: Let me give you whole scenario . I am developing mouse driver on android there is an intent service that will establish connection to the mouse then read data from mouse like (x y coordinate data , left right click ) , so intent service broadcast this data , another service Input method service will receive broadcast messages get the  currently running activity from activity manager and dispatch the motion event , either left or right up or down . If key is pressed then keydown event is dispatched to the foreground activity .

Comment: If you are developing a mouse driver, you need to deliver the events through the low-level event system (being read from the kernel drivers producing events), or it will just not work.  The dispatch methods are there for ViewGroup classes to override the dispatching behavior as events flow down the view hierarchy; they are not for injecting new events.