# How to call functions from a custom base adapter

Tags: android, checkbox, baseadapter

I have this code in my custom base adapter. I have a check boxes on each row in a list view, which are working fine and i have them linking with my database. However, when the check box is ticked i want to update the contents of a textview which is in the main activity this custom base adapter was started from.

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder;

  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();

   holder.bought = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_bought);

   convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }


  holder.bought.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
             //update textview in activity
          }else{

          }
      }
  });
```

Here is the function i would like to call when the check box is ticked, which is also where you see the custom base adapter beginning shown above.

```
  private void fillData() {
      db.updateTag(tag);

      totalCostView.setText(String.valueOf(tag.cost));
        listOfTodos = db.getAllToDosByTag(nameOfList);

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listItems);
        lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, list, tag));

    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create `getInstance` method in your `activity` then call the method through it as following:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{
   private static MainActivity sMainActivity;

   @override
   private void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
       sMainActivity = this;
```

And create the get method

```
public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return sMainActivity;
}
```

Then in your `adapter` call the following line:

```
MainActivity.getInstance().fillData();
```

Note: Make sure that the `activity` is currently opened to avoid any `NullPointerExceptions`

Comment: how can MainActivity return a "this" from a static method?

Comment: I have did this in my code before by creating an `instance` the refer to `this` in my `onCreat` so I expect this to work also because it is a matter of addresses not object, Am I true? @NameSpace

Comment: I know you can create a static field to hold an instance, and return that from a static method, like one of the [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324856/get-instance-of-currently-running-activity).  But if you generate a "this" from within a static method, how does the "this" know which instance to refer to?  I suppose in theory it could find the only one in existence, but I don't believe it does; Eclipse won't even let me compile the statement.

Comment: That`s a good notice, so the best if to instantiate an instance onCreating the `activity` and return this instance if not equal null. Thanks @NameSpace

Comment: Thanks very much! I managed to get this working, but yes I had to avoid using static.

Answer (score 0):

assumming that you have your adapter as an inner class , you can call outer class methods like

```
OutherCLassName.this.fillData();
```

if you have your Adapter in separated file, you just need to pass an **Activity** trought adapter constructor and then just call the method on activity variable :)

Comment: Thanks for the response - it is in a different class. How is it you pass the activity through? I currently call the adapter and pass in "this" as you can see above. Is this what you mean? Then it is saved as a context in the adapter. But I can't seem to find a way to call the function with that context.