# Catching app events from external library

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context, android-library

I'm working in a external library that basically needs to catch all the touch events, and detect the activities life cycles, I was struggle a couple of days till I figure out a way to go, so I started as Flurry does,
what does it means?
Passing the `Activity` `Context` to my main class in the library.
After that, I was thinking that getting the root view from this `context` I can have
access to the children views somehow, and with that assign a `touch listener` event to each one.

```
public class MainLibraryClass {
   private Context context; 
   private ViewGroup rootView;

   public void init(Context context) {
       this.context = context;

       // Get the parent view form the context related
       rootView = (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView()
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    initEvents();
}
```

This is the way that I assigned a `touch listener` event to the root view

```
rootView.setOnTouchListener(customTouchListenerEvent);
```

And it works, at least for the main view, but for the element on this (buttons, image Views, textViews, etc) :(

The solution that passed by my mind was get the current `Activity` and with that get every single view on this, and assign a new touch event listener:

```
   private void getCurrentActivity() {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    componentInfo.getPackageName();

    // TODO Read and assign touch events to the views on the activity
}
```

After read the last response of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324856/get-instance-of-currently-running-activity) 
I just realize that setting a new touch event listener to every single view (again) gonna be a super mess by the time
I wondering if there are another way to get the event in my library without duplicate the listeners or how can I access to the events and activities from the context?

Comment: implement the package's interface then apply the code on the overriden method

Comment: This can be good If I were working with one app, unfortunately this library needs to be implemented in several apps with different package names